# Azure AD B2C Application won't show up as an option to add role assignment. (Graph API)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm following this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga

And I found another question answered that I thought fit my case:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/199433/can39t-add-role-assignments-to-azure-b2c-applicati.html

My problem is that the app that I registered will not appear as an option when I try to follow the "Enable user delete and password update" portion of the documentation.

I am also mindful of the notice "Please allow a few minutes to for the permissions to fully propagate." But I've at it for 2 hours now, so I don't think that is the problem.

Here is my App and its API permissions:

[image: Here is my App and its API permissions:]

And my B2C Tenant:

[image: And my B2C Tenant:]

Comment: It seems, that this is not supported, even if it is stated in the docs. If I try to add the app to the role via graph api this is the response: "Objects of type Application cannot be assigned to roles"

Comment: I asked this same question over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/229991/azure-ad-b2c-application-won39t-show-up-as-an-opti.html) and got a response from Microsoft. Essentially, they don't know why it is happening, and the support engineers have been contacted. I will try to update here once I receive a response there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has answered this question [on this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/229991/azure-ad-b2c-application-won39t-show-up-as-an-opti.html?childToView=234678#answer-234678) as follows:

Hi All · Thank you for reaching out.

There seems to be an issue with the UI. I will report the issue to the product team and get it addressed.

However, as of now, you can follow below steps and use PowerShell to add application to the User Administrator role:

- Install latest Azure AD PowerShell Module.
- Run Connect-AzureAD -TenantId Your_B2CTenant.onmicrosoft.com and sign in with Global Administrator account in that tenant.
- Run Get-AzureADDirectoryRole cmd and copy the object id of the User Administrator role.
- Navigate to Azure AD > Enterprise Applications > Search the app and copy the object id of the app.
- Run Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId object_ID_copied_in_Step3 -RefObjectId object_ID_copied_in_Step4 cmdlet.

To verify, navigate to Azure AD B2C > Roles and Administrators > User Administrator. You should see the application present under this role